# Can I have 2 public subnets one one EC2 instance for creating a load balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, subnet

So I eventually want to set up a classic load balancer on AWS and I have a VPC with 2 public subnets, but now I am not sure if I can use those two subnets for that one EC2 instance or do I need two ec2 instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some thoughts:

- What's the point of a load balancer with only one instance? If you scale down to one instance that would make sense, but planning for only one instance all the time would have minimal benefits. Load balancers do offer benefits, they're a reverse proxy that offer your instance some protection against internet based threats.
- Technically you can load balancer to one or more instances
- Classic load balancer is not often used these days, best select from the more modern ALB / NLB unless you have a really odd edge case they can't cater for

Comment: thank you. First timer with this, wanted to check in with someone with more experience.

Comment: No worries. I've been doing AWS for a good while now and you're not doing anything too crazy. AWS Training can be really useful, Cloud Guru is one place that offers it.

Comment: yes, I am actually following A Cloud Guru, Ryan from Australia, but he never made clear when creating a load balancer how many instances of ec2 to create, perhaps he was inferring it and I just did not catch on.